# How to logout of Facebook and Gmail with api during native app automation?

Tags: facebook, gmail, appium-ios

I'm automating native iOS app with Appium. Which has scenarios related to connect with facebook or gmail.

As base state, I want to make sure user has logged out of facebook and gmail.

Please let me know if this is possible with api calls?

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here.

Workaround: As a precondition, open the safari browser on device and logout. Use SafariLaucher https://github.com/budhash/SafariLauncher, create webapp steps to logout in BeforeClass/Method.